# sending form data with file and boolean values in angular2

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a form where the user selects from a set of check boxes and also selects a picture. I'm sending this form from an angular2 front-end to an asp.net core web api backend. The issue i am having is that when i send the data, only the image file is sent, all the check box data which is in boolean is ignored. It's my first time doing this so i'm not sure how to handle it.

Below is the code i am using for adding the data to a form data

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('ReturnFaceLandMarks', this.formViewModel.ReturnFaceLandmarks);
    formData.append('ReturnFaceId', this.formViewModel.ReturnFaceId);
    formData.append('age', this.formViewModel.age);
    formData.append('facial_hair', this.formViewModel.facial_hair);
    formData.append('gender', this.formViewModel.gender);
    formData.append('glassed', this.formViewModel.glassed);
    formData.append('head_pose',"false");
    formData.append('smile', "true");
    formData.append('file', this.formViewModel.img);
```

and down here is the post request

```
 detect(data: any): Promise<any>
  {   
      return this.http.post(this.serverUrl+"face/detect/", data, { headers: this.headers })
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The file gets sent to my web api, but the only file i see there is the image file.Below is my request payload.
[image]

Comment: what is the model like in the web api? i.e the post method in /face/detect/

Comment: @Yordan the web api is receiving an Iform file

Comment: add a content-type header field to the bool data

Comment: @Yordan i'm sorry but i do not know how to do that. could you show me an example

Comment: please check this out. I hope it helps  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/03/25/httpclient-and-empty-items-in-a-multipart-form-post/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issues working with Angular and .Net

The solution that worked best for me was to either create a class (model) that the FormData mapped to or to specify the web api controller method parameters with the [FromForm] attribute.

```
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file, [FromForm] bool smile) {
   ...
}
```